# How should questions that does not need an answer be flagged?

Tags: support, questions, flags

Basically, someone asks a question but posts a comment saying they solved their problem. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226600/register-form-not-working-values-are-correct-but-nothing-in-database) does not need an answer as the OP already figured out their problem. How should a question like this be flagged and closed?

Comment: Is the question on topic? Then there is no need to flag it at all.

Comment: Otherwise, use the standard close options. There is no need to flag a question that has a vague answer in the comments.

Comment: Well, since a comment isn't considered an answer you shouldn't vote to close it at all. Either ask the OP in a comment to post their solution as an answer, or write one in case the OP posted their solution in that comment as well.
If it turns out the problem was a simple typo flag the question as such.

Comment: Questions are not here to only help the asker; they're meant to help everyone else with the same problem in the future.  We don't close questions because the asker no longer needs an answer.

Comment: The question I linked, for example, has no answers or comments other than the OP stating that they solved their problem. Perhaps, asking them to post their solution is a good idea.